# como puedo aplicar un DISTINCT a esta consulta?

Tags: oracle

```
SELECT ADM.GROUP_ID, ADM.GROUP_NAME, ADM.CUG_ID, ADM.ADMIN_SUBS_ID, 
    ADM.MSISDN MSISDN_ADMIN, ADM.SUBSCRIPTION_STATE ADMIN_STATE,
    SUBS.MSISDN MEMBER_MSISDN, SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, 
    SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_STATE MEMBER_STATE,
    SUBS.GROUP_ID_1, SUBS.GROUP_ID_2, SUBS.GROUP_ID_3
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT  GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME, CUG_ID, ADMIN_SUBS_ID,
        MSISDN, SUBSCRIPTION_STATE, GROUP_ID_1, GROUP_ID_2, GROUP_ID_3
    FROM PMS.PMS_GROUP G
        LEFT JOIN PMS.PMS_SUBSCRIPTION S
        ON SUBSCRIPTION_ID = ADMIN_SUBS_ID
    WHERE SUBSCRIPTION_STATE = 5) ADM
LEFT JOIN
    PMS.PMS_SUBSCRIPTION SUBS
    ON (ADM.GROUP_ID = SUBS.GROUP_ID_1
        OR ADM.GROUP_ID = SUBS.GROUP_ID_2
        OR ADM.GROUP_ID = SUBS.GROUP_ID_3)
WHERE ADM.MSISDN <> SUBS.MSISDN
AND SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_STATE = 2
ORDER BY ADM.GROUP_ID;
```

si la aplico la consulta  asi vuelve y me muestra los datos repetidos
lo que quiero es lograr que no me repita  datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, brinda un poco mas de información de lo que se trata y que quieres lograr con tu consulta.

Comment: bueno  lo que quiero es que  me saque los duplicados  con la consulta como puede ver hay aplico el distinct  y en la imagen muestra el resultado de la consulta   como se ve siguen estando repetidos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu consulta no regresa información duplicada. Oracle considera un registro duplicado cuando "los valores de todos los campos son idénticos en un solo registro". En el ejemplo que muestras si existen valores duplicados para el campo ADMIN_SUBS_ID, sin embargo, los campos SUBS.MSISDN y SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID hacen que los registros sean únicos (no repetidos).

En caso de que requieras que se agrupen por este campo, te recomiendo realices un DISTINCT (en el select de la parte superior) omitiendo estos campos, sin embargo, ten en cuenta que el resto de los campos podrá contener en algún momento distintos valores que hagan que los registros sean únicos.

Answer (score 0):

El `Distinct` debes aplicarlo en un `SELECT`.

En una tabla o conjunto de tablas los resultados de una columna obtenidos a través de una sentencia `SELECT` pueden aparecer en varias ocasiones, con `DISTINCT` dicha columna mostrara **un único resultado para cada valor diferente**.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ADM.GROUP_ID, ADM.GROUP_NAME, ADM.CUG_ID, ADM.ADMIN_SUBS_ID, 
    ADM.MSISDN MSISDN_ADMIN, ADM.SUBSCRIPTION_STATE ADMIN_STATE,
    SUBS.MSISDN MEMBER_MSISDN, SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, 
    SUBS.SUBSCRIPTION_STATE MEMBER_STATE,
    SUBS.GROUP_ID_1, SUBS.GROUP_ID_2, SUBS.GROUP_ID_3

FROM...
```

Con el código anterior conseguirás solo se muestre un resultado para cada  ADM.GROUP_ID distinto.

Answer (score 0):

La solución mas simple es que hagas un sub-query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (TU_QUERY);
```

Si eso sigue sin funcionar, tendrías que evaluar que campo de tu consulta hace que el DISTINCT no los desduplique, probablemente te falte alguna condición en el ON o el WHERE.

Recuerda que el DISTINCT solo des-duplica si y solo si todo las columnas de la consulta son iguales, si no tendrías que aplicar un GROUP BY de los campos llave y usar alguna función de agregación (SUM, MAX, etc.) en el resto de campos.

Para listar los registros duplicados puedes usar:

```
SELECT GROUP_ID,COUNT('*') FROM (TU_QUERY) GROUP BY GROUP_ID HAVING COUNT('*')>1;
```